# Issue with generic type in a react-hook-form component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying to build a field array component in TypeScript that can work with more than one form. To do this, I am trying to use a generic to pass the form fields interface, but I can't quite get the types right (it is working, but has type issues).

If I import my interface (that describes my form's fields) and use it in place of `T` everything works as expected, but with the generic I get some errors. Here's what I have:

```
import type { Control, FieldErrors, FieldValues } from 'react-hook-form'
import { useFieldArray } from 'react-hook-form'

interface Props<T extends FieldValues> {
  control: Control<T>
  errors: FieldErrors<T>
}

export function Tags<T extends FieldValues>({
  control,
  errors,
}: Props<T>) {
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    name: 'tags',
    control,
    keyName: 'key',
    rules: { required: 'Please choose at least one tag' },
  })

  const handleTagChange = (tag: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value, checked } = tag.target

    if (checked) {
      append({ id: value, name })
    } else {
      const index = fields.findIndex((field) => field.id === value)
      remove(index)
    }
  }

  const tags = [
    { id: '1', name: 'tag1' },
    { id: '2', name: 'tag2' },
    { id: '3', name: 'tag3' },
  ]

  return (
    <>
      <div role="group" aria-labelledby="policy-tags">
        <p id="policy-tags">Tags</p>
        <div>
          {tags.map((tag) => (
            <>
              <label key={tag.id} htmlFor={tag.name}>
                {tag.name}
              </label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={(e) => handleTagChange(e)}
                key={tag.id}
                name={tag.name}
                value={tag.id}
                checked={fields.some((field) => field.id === tag.id)}
              />
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
        {errors?.tags?.root && <p>{errors.tags.root?.message || ''}</p>}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

And the implementation:

```
<Tags<IFormFields> control={control} errors={errors} />
```

I am seeing these errors:

[image]

[image]

The component functions as expected, I just can't get the types right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close!
The following changes are required to make TypeScript understand how the data is flowing:

- `useFieldArray` can be fed 3 type arguments; `TFieldValues`, `TFieldArrayName` and `TKeyName` (see [ts docs](https://react-hook-form.com/ts#UseFieldArrayReturn))
  As `useFieldArray` takes part as a field in your form, it requires name (`TFieldArrayName`) to be part of `TFieldValues`.
  `useFieldArray` tries to infer the form fields through the `control` type, but that ends up - via your `Props` - at the empty `FieldValues`, where `'tags'` does not exists.

  So as [@Moussa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15628525/moussa-bistami) stated, you have to provide a partial form with only the necessary tag field.
- The control property type must be overridden due to complex internal generic pass-through (caused by `_subjects.state` and `_reset` properties, those can not match `T` to `FieldValues` although `T` extends `FieldValues`).
  By setting `TFieldValues` to `Partial<T>`, the `control` type can safely be overridden using `Control<FieldValues>`

## Solution

With the above changes, the following piece of code should work:

```
interface PartialTagForm {
  tags: { id: string; name: string }[]
}

export function Tags<T extends FieldValues>({ control, errors }: Props<T>) {
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray<
    Partial<PartialTagForm>,
    'tags',
    'key'
  >({
    name: 'tags',
    control: control as Control<FieldValues>,
    keyName: 'key',
    rules: { required: 'Please choose at least one tag' },
  })
```

## Bonus

As `tags` should always be available as key in your form, you should replace `FieldValues` by `PartialTagForm` in `Tags<T extends FieldValues>`.
Note that `tags` then also must be available in your `IFormFields`

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, you must define the shape of your type and provide it to the `useFieldArray` hook as follows:

```
interface FormValues {
  tags: { id: string; name: string }[];
}

const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray<FormValues>({
  name: 'tags' as const, // 'as const' asserts 'tags' as a literal type
  control,
});
```

doing this should also fix the second issue please try the above and post a reply with your update I'll try to edit the answer accordingly.